# Force.com IDE Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, salesforce, force.com

When I am trying to download Force.com Plugin for Eclipse, it was unsuccessful and gives me the following error.Please give me a solution for this.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Force.com IDE 18.0.0.201004191706 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 18.0.0.201004191706)
Software being installed: Force.com IDE 19.0.0.201006111421 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 19.0.0.201006111421)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Force.com IDE API 24.0.0.201202271900 (com.salesforce.ide.api 24.0.0.201202271900)
Force.com IDE API 16.0.0.200906151227 (com.salesforce.ide.api 16.0.0.200906151227)
Force.com IDE API 23.0.0.201110271337 (com.salesforce.ide.api 23.0.0.201110271337)
Force.com IDE API 23.0.1.201111041306 (com.salesforce.ide.api 23.0.1.201111041306)
Force.com IDE API 25.0.0.201206181021 (com.salesforce.ide.api 25.0.0.201206181021)
Force.com IDE API 27.0.0.201302151147 (com.salesforce.ide.api 27.0.0.201302151147)
Force.com IDE API 23.0.0.201110271426 (com.salesforce.ide.api 23.0.0.201110271426)
Force.com IDE API 18.0.0.201004191706 (com.salesforce.ide.api 18.0.0.201004191706)
Force.com IDE API 20.0.1.201011121559 (com.salesforce.ide.api 20.0.1.201011121559)
Force.com IDE API 24.0.0.201202291502 (com.salesforce.ide.api 24.0.0.201202291502)
Force.com IDE API 24.0.0.201202291629 (com.salesforce.ide.api 24.0.0.201202291629)
Force.com IDE API 19.0.0.201006111421 (com.salesforce.ide.api 19.0.0.201006111421)
Force.com IDE API 14.0.2.200812101436 (com.salesforce.ide.api 14.0.2.200812101436)
Force.com IDE API 15.0.0.200902181452 (com.salesforce.ide.api 15.0.0.200902181452)
Force.com IDE API 26.0.0.201210261118 (com.salesforce.ide.api 26.0.0.201210261118)
Force.com IDE API 23.0.2.201201091635 (com.salesforce.ide.api 23.0.2.201201091635)
Force.com IDE API 15.0.1.200903241010 (com.salesforce.ide.api 15.0.1.200903241010)
Force.com IDE API 14.0.0.200810271707 (com.salesforce.ide.api 14.0.0.200810271707)
Force.com IDE API 15.0.2.200904191137 (com.salesforce.ide.api 15.0.2.200904191137)
Force.com IDE API 20.0.0.201010190848 (com.salesforce.ide.api 20.0.0.201010190848)
Force.com IDE API 25.0.0.201206151446 (com.salesforce.ide.api 25.0.0.201206151446)
Force.com IDE API 14.0.1.200810311433 (com.salesforce.ide.api 14.0.1.200810311433)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Force.com IDE 18.0.0.201004191706 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 18.0.0.201004191706)
To: com.salesforce.ide.api [18.0.0,19.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Force.com IDE 19.0.0.201006111421 (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 19.0.0.201006111421)
To: com.salesforce.ide.api [19.0.0,20.0.0)
```

Comment: It looks like you might have an old version installed. Try uninstalling the old version first then adding the new one.

Answer (score 1):

It seams that you are using Juno or Indigo. I had the same issue with these versions. Try [Helios](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1).